# Laravel resource controllers for both API and non-API use

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, restful-url

After creating a resource controller `PhotosController` for a website that also does AJAX calls to the API, it appears that the resource controller can be used on both the normal website and as the API.

This displays a HTML page for `Photo` with id = 1

```
http://domain.com/photos/1
```

and Javascript uses the following which updates the `Photo` resource and returns a JSON response

```
PUT http://domain.com/api/v1/photos/1
```

**Question:** Will we have 2 `PhotoControllers`, one to handle API usage and one for non-API?

Answer (score 6):

No. You can have two separate routes point to the same controller and action.

```
Route::get('/photos/1', 'PhotoController@index');
Route::get('/api/v1/photos/1', 'PhotoController@index');
```

Then, in your controller methods, you can test whether the request is from Ajax or not.

```
if (Request::ajax()) {
    // Do some crazy Ajax thing
}
```

Comment: Why do you include the domain? To me, that's a DRY issue, and somewhat unnecessary...

Comment: You wouldn't want to. I changed edited my answer. Thanks for pointing that out, @Mike Anthony

Answer (score 2):

I use a route group with prefix for API calls:

```
Route::resource('venue', 'VenueController');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function(){
    Route::resource('venue', 'VenueController', array('only' => array('index', 'show')));
});
```

Then, in the controller, I use this condition:

```
if (Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix() == 'api') {
    return Response::json($venues->toArray());
}
```